# Best way to implement auto suggestions feature?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, autocomplete, autosuggest

Currently, we are manually making a request call for suggestion data with every keyup, but cancelling the previous call made before making the new one. Is there a better way to do this with Angular.js/Node.js, or perhaps some other library that we can simply import? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which CSS framework are you using?

Comment: you can look at `typeahead` from `angular-ui`

Comment: @entre It appears to me that this library is dependent on jquery. Is there a way around this? Meaning, without jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you can do is to send requests only after some small time of not typing, instead of on every keyup.

So for example when someone quickly types 20 characters then right now you're making 20 requests and cancel most of them. But if you were sending a request only after for example half a second of non-typing then it would be just one request, with the same result.